# How can I use my extended method on my constructor in another class?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, extension-methods

I would like to use a method in a constructor that belongs another class, but I`m getting the error: StorageCtrl.getItemsFromStorage is not a function

Here is part of my code:

```js
//Storage Controller
class StorageCtrl {
  constructor() {
    this.getItemsFromStorage();
  }

  getItemsFromStorage() {
    let items;
    if (localStorage.getItem('items') === null) {
      items = [];
    } else {
      items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
    }
    return items;
  }
```

This is the class that I`m getting the error from:

```js
// Model 
class TaskModel extends StorageCtrl {
  constructor(id, name, calories) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.calories = calories;

    // Data Structure / State
    this.data = {
      items: [
         {id: 0, name: 'Steack Dinner', calories: 1200},
         {id: 1, name: 'Cookie', calories: 400},
         {id: 2, name: 'Eggs', calories: 300}
           ],
      items: StorageCtrl.getItemsFromStorage(),  // The method that I`m trying to use
      currentItem: null,
      totalCalories: 0
    }
  }
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help or suggestion.

Comment: `StorageCtrl.getItemsFromStorage()` should be `this.getItemsFromStorage()`

Comment: Why did you try to access the method via `StorageCtrl.getItemsFromStorage`?

Comment: you can access only static methods with this invocation style `StorageCtrl.getItemsFromStorage`.  As @VLAZ mentioned, it should be `this` instead of `StorageCtl`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, that worked. I really appreciated that.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code,since you inherited `StorageCtrl` Class in `TaskModel`.There is no need for creating object or static reference for accessing `getItemFromStorage`.
It would be appropriate if you use `this`, since getItemStorage is also method of TaskModel.

So `StorageCtrl.getItemFromStorage` should be `this.getItemFromStorage()` and it should work.

If you want it to be two different classes.

You can do it by

1. creating object and then accessing it.

for example,

```
class Sample{
  sayHello(){
    console.log('Hello');
  }
}
```

To access `sayHello` from other class, you need to create object and then access it.

```
class Sample1{
  constructor(){
    var obj = new Sample();
    obj.sayHello();
  }
}
```

2. static method.

We declare method as static as

```
class Sample{
  static sayHello(){
    console.log('Hello');
  }
}
```

and access `sayHello` method like this

```
class Sample1{
  constructor(){
    Sample.sayHello();
  }
}
```

Here are few references

[https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-inheritance-javascript/](https://medium.com/@yyang0903/static-objects-static-methods-in-es6-1c026dbb8bb1)

https://medium.com/@yyang0903/static-objects-static-methods-in-es6-1c026dbb8bb1

https://javascript.info/static-properties-methods

Comment: OP is already extending the class, so there is no need to create a new instance of the parent class in order to access the method.

Comment: yes, I mentioned that part as well in the beginning. However, my example does not inherit any class.